# Can I get the stack trace without an exception/error in Sentry?

Tags: sentry

Trying to see if I can get the stack trace (for both backend and frontend) on Sentry, without actually creating an error. I don't need to create an event, just sort of fetch whatever the last 50 actions (breadcrumbs, I believe?) were. Any help would be much appreciated!

Using Python for backend.

Answer (score 1):

you can just do a `captureMessage` instead, but remember to enable the `attach_stacktrace` mode -> https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/configuration/options/#attach-stacktrace